# Why don't we multiply Ksp and Kf?

Tags: equilibrium

My understanding is that for a process with two reactions having the equilibrium constants K1 and K2, K for the full process is K = K1 x K2. However, in this problem in my book where complexation increases solubility of CuS in water, they just argue that Kf >> Ksp and drives the reaction forward. Why is it not K = Kf x Ksp?
Thank you.

The problem:
A 0.1 mol sample of CuS is added to 1.00 L of 1.00 M NH3. What is the final concentration of the complex ion, tetraaminecopper(II)?

$$\ce{CuS(s) <=> Cu^2+ (aq) + S^2- (aq)}\ \ \  K_\mathrm{sp} = \pu{8E-37}$$

$$\ce{Cu^2+ (aq) + 4NH3 (aq) <=> [Cu(NH3)4]^2+ (aq)}\ \ \   K_f = \pu{1.1E13}$$

The answer key: $K_f$ will drive the dissociation of $\ce{CuS}$ forward such that the amount of $\ce{Cu^2+}$ available to react is [Cu2+] = .1 mol/1.00 L = 0.1 M, and due to the 1:1 relationship between $\ce{Cu^2+}$ and the complex ion, the concentration of the complex ion will also be 0.1 M. I believe this implies the overall K >> 1, rather than ~10^-24, which it would be if we multiplied Ksp and Kf.

Comment: Do not try to mechanically apply multiplication, think rather when we do it, when we do not and why for both. Analyze the task from the scratch, using both constants and forget the a priori multiplication for a while.

Comment: No one is stopping you from calculating the product between the two constants. However, whether this is relevant or not in the context of your problem is highly debatable.